# I need your help, opinions and correct ways to complete my project (Server-Client but I've stuck in data conversation and generic types)

Tags: c#

Okay, This is going to be long.

First of all I want to introduce you what I do need:

I need suggestions, your opinions, the right method behind this server-client data sending & receiving (if I'm wrong at somepoint)

Need to fix points where I stuck (I've pointed them)

Firstly I've made a class which is actually a buffer and converter for sending & receiving data. I mean there is(was) methods like:

```
void Write(byte arg)
void Write(ushort arg)
void Write(DateTime arg)
void Write(DateTime[] arg)

byte ReadByte()
int[] ReadIntArray(int count)
```

etc. etc. This methods actually writes bytes to a `List<byte> motherBuffer` . And there is methods like Send() sends data via stream and Clear() clears the buffer.

```
public void Clear()
{
    motherBuffer.Clear();
}
public void Send()
{
    Stream.Write(motherBuffer.ToArray(), 0, motherBuffer.Count);
}
```

Firstly the logic of my class was, like this:

```
    public void Write(byte arg)
    {
        motherBuffer.Add(arg)
    }
    public void Write(short arg)
    {
        foreach (byte b in BitConverter.GetBytes(arg)) // calls Write(byte) twice
           Write(b);
    }
    public byte ReadByte()
    {
        if (!IsDataAvailable())
            throw new Exception("No-data is available to be read.");
        else
            return (byte)Stream.ReadByte();
    }
    public short ReadShort()
    {
        return BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[2] { ReadByte(), ReadByte() }, 0); // calls readbyte twice
    }
    public short[] ReadShortArray(int length)
    {
        short[] r = new short[length];

        for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++)
            r[i] = ReadShort();

        return r;
    }
```

but after I've figured out there is a better method, I've changed this something like:

```
        public void Write(byte arg)
        {
            motherBuffer.Add(arg);
        }
        public void Write(byte[] arg)
        {
            motherBuffer.AddRange(arg);
        }
        public void Write(short arg)
        {
            Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(arg)); // this time only calls Write(byte[]) once
        }
        public byte ReadByte()
        {
            if (!IsDataAvailable())
                throw new Exception("No-data is available to be read.");
            else
            {
                int read = Stream.ReadByte();

                if (read < 0)
                    throw new Exception("End of stream -1");
                else
                    return (byte)read;
            }
        }
        public byte[] ReadByteArray(int count)
        {
            if (!IsDataAvailable())
                throw new Exception("No-data is available to be read.");
            else
            {
                byte[] read = new byte[count];
                int result = Stream.Read(read, 0, count);

                if (result <= 0)
                    throw new Exception("End of stream -1");
                else
                    return read;
            }
        }
        public short ReadShort()
        {
            return BitConverter.ToInt16(ReadByteArray(2), 0); // this time calls once too
        }
        public short[] ReadShortArray(int length)
        {
            short[] r = new short[length];

            for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++)
                r[i] = ReadShort();

            return r;
        }
```

After All this, I thought why didn't I do something like (and really felt bad because This is more short way, also this is where I was going to stuck):

```
        public T Read<T>() where T : int // I don't actually know what 'where T : int' does just tried for 'return (int)-1;' 
        {
            if (!IsDataAvailable())
                throw new Exception("No-data is available to read.");

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte))
            {
                int read = Stream.ReadByte();

                if (read < 0)
                    return (int)-1; // STUCK HERE
                else
                    return read as T; // STUCK HERE
            }
            else
            {
                 // STUCK HERE : because I don't know how to return & convert type of 'T'
            }
        }

        public int ReadArray<T>(T[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            if (!IsDataAvailable())
                throw new Exception("No-data is available to read.");

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte))
            {
                return Stream.Read(buffer as byte[], offset, count);
            }
            else
            {
                int m = 2; // multplier for example: this is short. I didn't figure out how to get it like sizeof(T)
                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[count * m]; // because I have to read twice amount of byte
                ReadArray<byte>(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length); 

                // I really don't know how could I use T with BitConverter.GetBytes( of T );
            }
        }
```

Comment: from what I understand it seems as you are reinventing the wheel, any reason for not using WCF or similar?. if you don't want to use wcf I guess you could serialize-deserialize anything without worrying on doing the conversions yourself

Comment: I just don't know too much. I don't know WCF. Going to check it

Answer (score 0):

Do not use generics, they are your enemy in this case. Just code what you want and go forward. What you could really improve is to use WCF or Remoting for network communication instead of manual marshaling.

Comment: I really feel doing wrong with C#. I mean there is a lot ready to use classes, methods etc. etc.. in .NET library. I think I'm wrong with trying to manual marshaling everything with C#. I feel like I should use more low-level languages like C or C++ even maybe assembly for speed. What do you think about it?

Comment: Well, you should to consider program's speed vs. your productivity dilemma. A common sense approach is this: code non-critical parts with nice existing tools such as WCF and Remoting; critical parts can be coded manually to get the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

This it one way of implementing Read:

```
public static T Read<T>(this Stream stream)
{
    object ret = null;

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte))
        ret = stream.ReadInt8();
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Int16))
        ret = stream.ReadInt16();
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Int32))
        ret = stream.ReadInt32();

    if (ret == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Unable to read type - " + typeof(T));
    return (T)ret;
}
public int ReadArray<T>(this Stream stream, T[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    for (int i = offset; i< count; i++) buffer[i] = stream.Read<T>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you mean I should use typeof(T) like a switch statement? and then call the methods I've previously done?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to peek into WCF a bit, as it already solves this problem better than you will ever be able to, and will let you focus on your application logic directly without worrying on how to move data between tiers;
[this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/11/02/wcf-101-the-simplest-wcf-example-you-ll-ever-see.aspx) is the shortest example of WCF I could find, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I really feel doing wrong with C#. I mean there is a lot ready to use classes, methods etc. etc.. in .NET library. I think I'm wrong with trying to manual marshaling everything with C#. I feel like I should use more low-level languages like C or C++ even maybe assembly for speed. What do you think about it?

Comment: I don't know what you need to do so it is hard to answer your question, in a 99% of the cases you'll be fine with c# and WCF, why are you worried?

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a year old but i thinks its worth adding to.

Ok first things first, as almost everybody else has said use WCF or other already implemented and tested system to communicate between tiers.

But to fill in your blanks:

`where T : int` is a generic constraint that says you will only return an `int`.  If `int` was replace with a class like`Stream` then you are saying you will only return a `Stream` or class derived from `Stream`.

Because you have a generic constraint of `int`, `typeof(T)` will never equal `typeof(byte)`.

The `as` operator can only be used on classes not structs.  Because of the generic constraint of `int`, `T` is a `struct`.

I can tell you that to address the issue with `return (int)-1;` you would need to first cast to `object` then to `T`, like so `return (T)(object)-1;`.  But I can’t really explain why as I don’t fully understand that aspect.  I can point you in the direction of Covariance and Contravariance in Generics http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx.

I hope you find this helpful.